# What is the purpose of the "fixedSearchFolder" and "fixedCombinedFolder" in MaxQuant?

Tags: proteomics, maxquant

What is the purpose of changing the `fixedSearchFolder` and `fixedCombinedFolder` in MaxQuant proteomics software? Is there any data that can be reused in other runs, so would it be good to use the same search folder for multiple runs? Or is it simply to direct temporary data and results data into different locations and each run should use a different folder?